# Are PNG images compatible with all the browsers?

Tags: image, web-standards

Do all modern browsers support PNG images, including Internet Explorer 6.0?

Comment: What is "16" is that supposed to be IE (as in Internet Explorer)? Is my encoding set up wrong? ;)

Comment: Although IE 6 still retains significant market share, I would hesitate to classify it as a "modern" browser. In fact, http://iedeathmarch.org gets somewhat militant about stamping it out. I prefer approaches like http://pushuptheweb.com, which is more subtle and applies to multiple browsers.

Answer (score 12):

IE 6.0 does not support *32-bit transparent* PNGs correctly. It renders the alpha channel (transparency) as a plain gray background. (Paletted PNGs with transparency are fine in IE6.) Most other browsers work correctly, though, including IE 7.0+, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Netscape, Opera, Epiphany, Konqueror...

The easiest solution for IE 6.0 transparency is to use GIFs instead. If this is not possible, a JavaScript and CSS solution is available at [24ways](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6).

Comment: IE 6 supports colour pallet PNG transparency fine, it's only 32bit PNG transparency that IE 6 doesn't work with (and there are some JS hacks that partially fix the problem)

Comment: There are "hacks" that will enable IE6 to correctly render Transparent PNG files - http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Comment: @Nate - I posted that in my 4th (I think) revision of the article. I'm not sure who was there first! :)

Comment: Also note that while IE7 does support 32-bit transparent PNGs, the implementation is horribly slow so you might want to avoid rendering pages full of transparent PNGs on IE7 as well.

Comment: Of course, who here has ever used a paletted PNG? (It reminds me of GIF, shudder - even though they're not the same.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do. With the exception that older IEs [cannot handle 24-bit transparent PNGs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294714) without some special hacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is only anecdotal but I remember that I had some issues using PNG's generated out of GIMP.  Firefox and Safari rendered them differently.

I'm remembering now.  One of the issues I came across was the difference between PNG colors and CSS colors in Safari.

Comment: Actually, GIMP always worked perfectly fine for me, when there's a long history of problems with IE and Photoshop-made PNGs: http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/articles/png-gamma.html

Answer (score 0):

As people have mentioned they won't work in IE6, you can use IE7-js to get them working to a decent degree there though
http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

It works by using some of the proprietary apis there - it also fixes lots of the other problems with ie6 dom and js.

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers support the PNG standard completely. Only IE6 does not as it does not support png transparency, but if your users are using IE6, it might be time you told them to upgrade.